# What am I to make of the layout of IDEAs default project structure?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project-structure

So ... I go File > New Project > Java Module and type in (1) a project name and (2) a module name and I get a project structure that makes sense to me:

[image: The modules are nested within the project]

Modules are nested within the project but the .idea file is left outside the scope of the Project Tool Window:

[image: the .idea file isn't in scope]

Why that? I'd assume one would like the .idea file to show up here?

And it can get crankier if I go File > New Project > Java Module and swap the order I fill in the project and module names (so I type (1) the module name followed by (2) the project name). In this case I will get a illogical project structure (I think) where later modules, along with the .idea file, become nested in the initial module :

[image: new modules are nested within the initial module]

This time I **can** peruse the .idea file from the Project Tool Window, even though I don't see why it would be nested in a module:

[image]

Now I **am** aware that one may tweak the project and module paths in the wizard, but I don't get this default behaviour and certainly not the way of nesting modules within modules along with the project .idea file.

In my perfect dreamworld, I would have the structure as in the ProjectNameFirst project above, **along** with the .idea file in the Project Tool Window.

So ... why aren't things like in my perfect dreamworld? 
What am I to make of the modules-within-modules nesting? 
and why wouldn't one always want the .idea file to be editable from within the Project Tool Window?

(this is under IDEA Ultimate 12.1.3)

Comment: Why would you want the .idea "file" to be editable at *all*?

Comment: I frankly don't have a use case. Maybe there isn't one. I assumed jetbrains made it available for a reason (or not?). It's included in the Project window when following one swim lane in the wizard and not in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the following from Jetbrains support:

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5487081#5487081

There is a bug in IDEA's creation wizard for the first case (ProjectNameFirst).